# How do I calculate levered equity beta without unlevered equity beta?

Tags: equities, finance, beta

I'm doing an assignment where I have liabilities including market and book values of long-term debt.

I also have capital including common stock, paid in capital, and accumulated earnings.

I've been able to calculate the structural weights using the debt or equity over the enterprise value.

I'm stuck on calculating the cost of financing, or levered equity beta, in this case however.

Is there a way to calculate equity beta with the information I've been given that I'm missing?

Comment: Why not just find the stock returns and calculate it yourself?

Comment: @John I'd love to, but it's a fictional company that I don't have returns on.

Comment: @Without having the exact text of your assignment, there's not much to go on. This is generally a site for quant professionals. Questions about fictional companies may not be on topic.

Comment: @John fair enough then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic for the reasons mentioned in @John 's comment.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just find it strange that CAPM is still being used to estimate the cost of equity when the Modigliani-Miller theorem on the irrelevance of capital structure -- which is not controversial, by the way -- clearly refutes doing so.

Comment: @DavidAddison Isn't the idea of levered and unlevered betas trying to take into Modigliani-Miller? What we observe in practice would be a levered beta, then you can compare between companies with the unlevered beta that corrects for the impact of debt financing.

Comment: @John. Actually, I didn't realize that. I get MM. But I am not sure if I can wrap my head around how the observed beta co-efficient between stock and market returns is causally related to anything which MM describes.

Comment: @DavidAddison MM Prop II makes a connection between the levered cost of equity and the unlevered cost of equity. If we estimate levered cost of equity using a WACC that includes a CAPM beta (which is a levered beta because we only observe stock prices that include leverage), then you can back out the unlevered cost of equity. I believe this is how the formula for unlevered beta are derived.

Comment: @John, I do not doubt you are right. I need to review my MM. I just fail to see how a linear regression on equity market returns contains any relevant information on firm risk.

Comment: @DavidAddison That's a deep observation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to have a try at this one.

The levered weighted average cost of capital, $\mathbb{r}_c$, is defined:

$\mathbb{r}_c = \frac{D+R+I(1-r_T)}{E+B} $

where financing costs are equal to dividends $D$, retained earnings $R$, and interest $I$; and:

$C$ is capital equal to equity, $E$, plus debt, $B$;

$E$ = 'common stock' + 'paid in capital' + 'accumulated earnings'; and,

$r_T$ is the tax shield.

In typical implementations of WACC, we rearrange as follows:

$r_c(E+B) = \frac{E}{E+B}(D+R) + \frac{B}{E+B}(I(1-r_T))  $

Equating:

$\frac{D+R}{E} := r_e$; and,

$\frac{I(1-r_T)}{B} := r_b$

allows us to solve by combination of terms for the cost of equity in familiar form:

$r_e \approx \frac{E+B}{E}(r_c - r_b ) + r_b$

which therefore implies that a CAPM-free equity beta can be set to:

$\beta_e = \frac{E+B}{E}$

For the risk-free rate, it is common to use a short-term treasury note. If the cost of capital is undefined, we can make it whatever we want it to be. If you believe the long-run return of the market is 7%, then that it was it is. Believe it or, no discount rate which approximates opportunity cost is the wrong one.